# Help changing the color and structure of a block diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a question about block diagrams in Latex.

I want to know how to put in red the lines of the square of a block diagram, I already know how to change the inside text and the arrows, but as I said I need help in changing the box line.

[image]

Thats the block diagram, and this is the code:

```
\begin{frame}{Desarrollo Diagrama en Bloques} 
Simplificamos el diagrama: 

\bigskip
\bigskip

\centering
        \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}] 

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
%Declara los nodos
\node [input, name=input] {}; 
\node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {}; 
\node [block, right of=sum] (Controller1) {\textcolor{red}{$\frac{K}{s}$}};
\node [block, right of=Controller1, node distance = 4.5cm] (system) {\textcolor{red}{$\frac{1}{s+1}$}}; 

\draw [->,red] (Controller1) -- node[name= ] {$ $} (system);
\node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
\node [block, below = 2 cm, right = 4cm] (Controller2) {$1+sK_h$}; 

%Ahora conectamos los bloques 

\draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$X(s)$} (sum); 
\draw [->,red] (sum) -- node {$ $} (Controller1); 
\draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$Y(s)$}(output); 
\draw [->] (y) |- (Controller2);
\draw [->] (Controller2) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$}  node [near end] {} (sum);

\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome!

1. You may be looking for the keys `draw=red`, and, instead of using `\textcolor`, `text=red`.
2. We usually present complete documents, which start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and load all style files such that they can be compiled.
3. `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, I replaced it by the corresponding `\tikzset` commands.
4. Your positioning methods are deprecated, I load `positioning` and use the corresponding syntax, e.g. instead of `right of=...` use `right=of ...` or `right=<distance> of ...`.
5. The `arrows` library is also a bit deprecated, and got replaced by `arrows.meta`.

Code and result:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Desarrollo Diagrama en Bloques} 
Simplificamos el diagrama: 

\bigskip
\bigskip

\centering
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em},
  sum/.style={draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm},
  input/.style={coordinate},
  output/.style={coordinate},}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1.5cm,>=Latex]
%Declara los nodos
  \node [input, name=input] {}; 
  \node [sum, right=of input] (sum) {}; 
  \node [block,text=red,draw=red,right=of sum] (Controller1) {$\dfrac{K}{s}$};
  \node [block,text=red,draw=red,right=of Controller1] (system) {$\dfrac{1}{s+1}$}; 
  \path (Controller1) --  node [block, below=2.5cm] (Controller2) {$1+s\,K_h$}
      (system);
  \node [output, right=of system] (output) {};
%Ahora conectamos los bloques 
  \draw [->,red] (Controller1) -- (system);

  \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$X(s)$} (sum); 
  \draw [->,red] (sum) -- node {$ $} (Controller1); 
  \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$Y(s)$}(output); 
  \draw [->] (y) |- (Controller2);
  \draw [->] (Controller2) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$}  node [near end] {} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I would draw your block diagram on the following way:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, 
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Desarrollo Diagrama en Bloques}
Simplificamos el diagrama:
    \begin{center}
\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw=#1,   % color of shape border
                minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em,
                text=#1},   % color of node contents
block/.default = red,       % default color is red
  sum/.style = {circle, draw=red, minimum size=3mm,
                node contents={}},
        }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, 
node distance = 6mm and 8mm,
            > = Stealth]
% Declara los nodos
\coordinate (input);
\node (sum)     [sum, right=of input];
\node (cntrl1)  [block, right=of sum]   {$\frac{K}{s}$};
\node (sys)     [block, right=of cntrl1]  {$\frac{1}{s+1}$};
\coordinate[right=of sys] (out);
\node (cntrl2)    [block=black, below= of $(cntrl1.south)!0.5!(sys)$] {$1+sK_h$};
% Lines
\draw   (input) edge ["$X(s)$"] (sum) 
        (sum)   edge[red] (cntrl1)
        (cntrl1)  edge[red] (sys)
        (sys) edge["$Y(s)$" {name=y}] (out);
\draw [->] (y |- sys) |- (cntrl2);
\draw [->] (cntrl2) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$}  (sum);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```