# Structure of the block diagram, input and output

Tags: shapes

I put too much information in my block diagram and now the input and output don't look right.

[image]

Is there a way to put larger arrows? and also I would like to know if X(s) and Y(s) can be a little bit farther form the block.

Here is the code for the block diagram:

```
\begin{frame}{Desarrollo Diagrama en Bloques} 

\centering 

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}] 

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
%Declara los nodos
\node [input, name=input] {}; 
\node [block, right of=input] (Controller1) {$\frac{K}{s^2+s(1+[K*K_h]+K}$};

\node [output, right of=Controller1] (output) {};

%Ahora conectamos los bloques 

\draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$X(s)$} (Controller1); 
\draw [->] (Controller1) -- node[name=y] {$Y(s)$}(output); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. You basically have to apply [the comments or my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520878/194703). Doing so yields

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Desarrollo Diagrama en Bloques}
\centering
\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em,inner xsep=1ex},
input/.style={coordinate}, output/.style={coordinate}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=Latex] %Declara los nodos 
  \node [input, name=input] {}; 
  \node [block, right=of input] (Controller1) {$\dfrac{K}{s^2+s(1+[K*K_h]+K}$};
  \node [output, right=of Controller1] (output) {};
  \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$X(s)$} (Controller1); \draw [->] (Controller1) -- node[name=y] {$Y(s)$}(output);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520873/help-changing-the-color-and-structure-of-a-block-diagram/520878#520878) on your previous question:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Desarrollo Diagrama en Bloques}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, 
node distance = 12mm,
 block/.style = {draw, minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em},
            > = Latex
                        ]
%Declara los nodos
\coordinate (input);
\node [block, right=of input] (Controller1) {$\frac{K}{s^2+s(1+[K*K_h]+K}$};
\coordinate[right=of Controller1] (output);

%Ahora conectamos los bloques
\draw [->] (input) to ["$X(s)$"] (Controller1);
\draw [->] (Controller1) to ["$Y(s)$"{name=y}] (output);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note: in above MWE is used syntax for nodes' positioning as defined in the `positioning` library, for example `right=of <coordinate name>`, where `node distance` is between nodes borders in difference from `right of = ...` which you use and where `node distance` is between center of nodes.

[image]